# How do I "click" with python selenium when object is not callable? Do I need javascript here, and how?

Tags: javascript, selenium, python-3.7

```
div = soup.find('div',{'class':'apply_button'})
div.input.click()
```

This gets the correct tag, but returns 'NoneType' object is not callable
SendKeys does not work either.

I don't understand javascript. Do I need to execute it to enable the button?
Or is there some simple way to enable the button so that it can be clicked?

```html
<div class="main_content">
  <p>
   <script type="text/javascript">dw(system_help_reboot);
      </script>Click the button below to restart the device.
  </p>
  <div class="apply_button">
   <label id="button_reboot">
    <script type="text/javascript">create_button(system_label_reboot,"reboot_apply_button");
    </script>
    <span class="button_wrapper" id="span_reboot_apply_button">
     <input class="button_dialog" id="reboot_apply_button" type="button" value="Reboot"/>
    </span>
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can't click on a bs object, you need selenium for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to run Javascript clicks through BeautifulSoup. But, if you want to use just Python / Selenium, you can JS click like this:

```
elementToClick = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='apply_button']")
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick)
```

Comment: if you find the element with selenium, you can just call regular a .click() method on it

Comment: Based on the problem description, it does not seem like a regular .click() will work on this. However, it will be worth trying anyway.